# How to compare user'r current location to other locations and display them in UITable View?

Tags: ios, json, swift, location, compare

I am developing an app in swift and I have to compare user's current location to the other locations taken from a JSON file. Then I have to display all of the locations which are in a certain range from the user's location. This range I take from a UISlider. I mean when the user selects 25km in the slider, the app has to determine the current user's location and display all of the fruits which are in this range.

```
   import UIKit
   import SwiftyJSON
   import MapKit
   import CoreLocation


 class TableViewController: UITableViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 @IBOutlet weak var Bar: UIToolbar!


@IBOutlet weak var LabelTest: UILabel! // this is the slider value, I segue it from the previous viewcontroller
var manager = CLLocationManager()

struct Fruit {
    let name : String
    let location : CLLocation
    let imageURL : NSURL
    let description : String
}
var fruits = [Fruit]()


func parseFruits() {
    guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("cities", withExtension: "json"), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
        print("Error finding JSON File")
        return
    }

    let jsonObject = JSON(data: jsonData)

    let fruitArray = jsonObject["fruits"].arrayValue
    for aFruit in fruitArray {
       let name = aFruit["Name"].stringValue
        let latitude = city["Latitude"] as! Double
        let longitude = city["Longitude"] as! Double
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
       let imageURL = aFruit["Picture"].stringValue
    let description = aFruit["Description"].stringValue

        let fruit = Fruit(name: name,location: location,imageURL: NSURL(string:imageURL)!, description: description )
        fruits.append(fruit)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseFruits()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fruits.count
    }



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as!  TableViewCell
     let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]
    cell.CellTitle.text = fruit.name
    cell.CellDescription.text = fruit.description


    let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL:(string: fruit.imageURL))!)
    cell.CellImage.image = image

    return cell
          }
```

Currently I am not calculating the user's current location and I am not comparing it, I would be glad if someone can show me how to do that.

edited:

```
   func CalculateDistance() {
    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    let destinationLocation = CLLocation(latitude:latitude, longitude: longitude)// latitude and longitude from the json file
    let distance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(destinationLocation)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to calculate the distance between two locations you can do the following:

```
let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
let destinationLocation = CLLocation(latitude: (dest.lat as NSString).doubleValue, longitude: (dest.long as NSString).doubleValue)
let distance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(destinationLocation)
```

Get the userLocation which is the current location of the user. Then you have the location of the destination and then calculate the distance with the help of the `distanceFromLocation` function which is a part of `CoreLocation`.

Then I have done a method that rounds the distance to nearest 5 meters:

```
var distanceToFive = roundToFive(distance)

private func roundToFive(x : Double) -> Int {
    return 5 * Int(round(x / 5.0))
}
```

You can of course change this to 10, 20 etc.

**Edit:**

And to get the current location:
Add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to the class inheritance. Declare `var locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and two variables one for lat and one for long. In `viewDidLoad` do

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
```

And then to get the location for the user declare the following methods:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        lat = location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error")
    }
```

Edit2:

```
func CalculateDistance() -> Int{
    let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    let destinationLocation = CLLocation(latitude:latitude, longitude: longitude)// latitude and longitude from the json file
    let distance = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(destinationLocation)

    return roundToFive(distance)
}

private func roundToFive(x : Double) -> Int {
    return 5 * Int(round(x / 5.0))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply I only can't get how do you get the users' current latitude and longitude which is substitute here:

Comment: let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply I completed the edited part of your answer. Would you please tell me where should I put the first part of your answer where we calculate the distance, because as you see I have to display the result in table view cells

Comment: @Dakata, place it as a method that returns an integer and then call it when you set the cell.

Comment: I am beginner in swift would you please show me an example, sorry if it is too stupid

Comment: please check the edited part I try to call the latitude and the longitude from the json file but they cannot be find

Comment: Thank you I got it , but how can I display them in the table view cells I want to see only these which are in the 5meters range

Comment: You can do this: if CalculateDistance() <= 5{ // place your code here }

Comment: do you have a email I want to show you what is happening